# I want my raw value in string format, but enum giving output only in int format. How can I make enum output in string value?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;


contract Library
{


enum Book  {WingsOfFire, RichDadPoorDad,DoItToday,AtomicHabits,TheArtOfSuccess}


struct StudentStruct
{
    string name;
    bool isStudent;
    uint rollNo;
    Book [] books;


}


mapping (address => StudentStruct) public studentStructs;
 address [] public students ;

 modifier OnlyIfRegistered ()
 {

   require (studentStructs[msg.sender].isStudent);
   _;

 }

function Register(  )public returns (bool success)
{
   require(!studentStructs[msg.sender].isStudent);
   students.push(msg.sender);
   studentStructs[msg.sender].isStudent=true;
   return true;


}


function Addbook ( Book B) public OnlyIfRegistered returns(bool success)
{
   studentStructs[msg.sender].books.push(B);
   return true;
     
}

function remove(uint index) public OnlyIfRegistered returns (bool success)
{

        //studentStructs[msg.sender].books.pop();   if we want romove only last element ......

       delete studentStructs[msg.sender].books[index]; //For specific index position
       return true;

}


 function getBook(address user,uint256 raw ) public view returns (string memory  )
  {

      
     studentStructs[user].books[raw]; 
   

  }

 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a solidity contract is compiled, it doesn't store the string values of the enum but only the int values. Hence to return string value from the contract you would either need to store something like below and return the string using the int value.

```
mapping(int => string) books;

constructor(){
 books[0] = "WingsOfFire";
 books[1] = "RichDadPoorDad";
}
```

Or you can use some if statements to check and return the string values and this would be gas efficient compared to the first option as there is no additional storage used.